# If n is an integer how to find k such that |n-2^k| is the smallest possible

Tags: c++, loops, visual-c++, conditional-statements

I have a problem to solve. First I have to check if the input **n** (positive integer) is a degree of three and if it's not, then to find a number *k* such that *|**n**-2^k|* is the smallest possible (if there are more than one *k* which satisfy the condition to find all of them). I did the first part but I don't know how to do the other. I think I have to use **else**, but I'm stuck. (I'm sorry if the code is ugly/not well written, I'm a beginner.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, m, countd = 0, k;
    do {
        cout << "Enter a positive integer: "; cin >> n;
    } while (n < 1);
    m = n;
    while (m % 3 == 0) {
        m /= 3;
        countd++;
    }if (m == 1) {
        cout << "3^" << countd << " = " << n << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: difficutl to help without spoiling the exercise. some hints: `std::log2` can help, doing the same you did for `3` for `2` instead can help

Comment: See the dupe, there are a number of solutions that will do what you want.